# Why Cordova battery-status event listeners are added to the window object?

Tags: events, mobile, cordova, battery

On the [Cordova (aka PhoneGap) documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html), all examples show event listeners added to the *document* object, for example:

`document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);`

...except for the three battery-status event listeners (batterystatus, batterycritical, batterylow), whose listeners are added to the *window* object. For example:

`window.addEventListener("batterycritical", yourCallbackFunction, false);`

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I was pulling my hair out why the event wasn't triggering. I did bind it to the document. Maybe they want to be compatible with Battery Status Api. http://www.w3.org/TR/battery-status/